# How to initialize an array of objects of a parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to initialize  an array of objects of a parametrized constructor . How can i do it in best possible way ?

```
   # include<iostream>
   # include<conio.h>
   # include<stdio.h>

   using namespace std;

   class A
   {
    public:
    int a;       
    A();
    A(int x)
    {
     a=x;
    }      
   };
   int main()
   {
    A *a1,a2(1);
    a1 = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A)*10); // equivalent to A[10]. 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) a1[i]=a2; // Initialization is important in any program.
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) cout<<a1[i].a; 
    getch(); 
    return 0;   
   }
```

This does work but is there some other way better than this ?

Comment: Why C's `malloc` and `getch()` instead of C++'s `new` and using iostream?

Comment: "*This does work*" No it doesn't; it invokes UB and only _appears_ to work.

Comment: @ildjarn What do you mean by it invokes only UB ? I did not get what you mean to say by UB ?

Comment: @Ritesh : [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ way would be to use a std::vector.

```
std::vector<A>   a1(10, 1);
```

creates 10 `A`'s initialized by `1`.

Comment: This requires A(int) to be not explicit I think ?

Comment: Probably, but it isn't in the example.

Comment: sure, wanted to be sure as I wanted to answer the very same thing but thought something was maybe amiss :)

Comment: @BoPersson Its not explicit in my case . However how does the destruction of these object take place  ? Is it just by calling clear function of vector ?

Comment: The vector will destroy itself when it goes out of scope (at the end of main). Or you can call clear if you want to empty it earlier.

Comment: @BoPersson In the above program if i declare a destructor i get a compilation error   [Linker error] undefined reference to `A::~A()'but without destructor code works fine

Comment: @Ritesh - You cannot just declare a destructor, you have to define it as well. But the above class doesn't need one.

Comment: A helpful clarification on this answer: vector will construct one object of type A based on an implicit conversion from int (because the constructor was not marked 'explicit' (as mentioned before). Then vector will use the copy constructor to construct 10 copies of this object.  If your class does not have a valid (default or user-defined) copy constructor, this method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved using std::vector constructor taking size and base element :

```
A a2(1);
std::vector<A> tab(10, a2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that `malloc` does not construct objects, and so calling `a1[i]=a2` is bad form.  It probably *seems to* work fine since they are POD-ish objects, but this is not the proper way to do C++.  It is undefined behavior, which is completely unpredictable.  It may work ten thousand times in a row, and then erase your bank account.  You should use `new` instead, which *also* constructs.  Or better yet, use a vector, like the other answers suggest.  Also, be sure that the default constructor initializes the data, and initialization will be less of a worry.

If you *really must* use malloc, the "correct way" to initialize is this:

```
std::uninitialized_copy(a1, a1+10, a2); //constructs and assigns
```

which is roughly equivalent to:

```
{
    int i=0;
    try {
        for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
           new(a1+i)A(a2); //constructs and initializes in the buffer
    } catch(...) { 
        try {
            for(; i>=0; --i)
               (a1+i)->~A(); //destroy if an error occured
        } catch(...) { 
            std::terminate();
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect the `A(int)` constructor to throw. Or the default copy constructor.

Comment: @BoPersson: true, but when he does this again with `std::string`, and is surprised that his program crashes?  I'll teach the generic correct (and easy!) way.

Comment: "*and I'm pretty sure it's undefined behavior*" It definitely is.

Comment: @ildjarn: I wasn't 100% sure, since the definition of POD has changed, and PODs are exceptions to some relevant rules.

Comment: @MooingDuck +1 For Genric Correct way :)