# c++03 Initializing a array of objects with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++03

This might be a simple question but I am trying to initialize an array of objects using a parameterized constructor. For example:

```
class A{
public:
    int b,c,d;
    A (int i, int j);
};

void A::A(int i, int j){
    d = rand()
    b = 2*i;
    c = 3*j;
}

void main(){
    A a[50]; /*Initialize the 50 objects using the constructor*/
}
```

I have already tried with vector initialization as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282097/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-of-a-parameterized-constructor) link however, since there are 2 parameters, this does not work.

Also, as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656576/how-can-i-initialize-an-array-of-objects-whose-constructor-require-two-or-more-a), it is not possible and tedious to manually enter 50 initialization values.

Is there a easier way. Also, i,j values are the same for all objects (available through main()) but `d` should be random value and differs from each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use std::generate

Example:

```
A generator(){ return A(1,2); }

std::generate( a, a + (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])), generator );
```

Comment: Good luck with that in C++03! (No lambdas until C++11).

Comment: Yes, I forgot this. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Why not supply default arguments to your two-argument constructor?

`A (int i = 0, int j = 0);`

Then it will stand in for the default constructor, and `A a[50];` will use it automatically 50 times.